# Delete Duplicate rows but retain the rows which has actual values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, analytics, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I have Bug ID and respective root cause, but for few bug IDs there is no root cause, so null is displayed.

I want to delete duplicate rows, if I select Bug ID column and remove duplicates, table is not retaining
rows which has actual value(Code error/Integaration error)

If I try to remove null from Root cause column and all rows which has null is getting deleted, I want to retain null for certain rows when there is no other actual root cause

for ex. Bug ID 567 should have null in Root cause column

```
    Bug ID 123 should have code error in Root cause column

    Bug ID 789 should have Integration error in Root cause column
```

Hope I am clear

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, click select all three columns at once, right click... remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the `Bug ID` and `State` columns, then transform the list of `Root Cause` values, to the distinct, non-null values:

```
= Table.Group(YourTable, {"Bug ID", "State"}, {{"Root Cause", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct(_[Root Cause])),", "), type text}})
```